# CakePHP 3: Redirect to https and non www

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, redirect

This is my CakePhp 3 htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]



    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]     
</IfModule>
```

I added the first condition and could make the next redirects

- **from** http://www.domain.com  **to** https://domain.com
- **from** https://www.domain.com **to** https://domain.com

But i can't redirect

- **from** http://domain.com **to** https://domain.com

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Change your first rule to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]     
</IfModule>
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this rule.

Comment: I think there are problems with cakephp directories, becasuse this rule redirect to: from domain.com to https://domain.com/app/webroot/

Comment: ok try `RewriteRule` line as `RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,L,NE]` after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Chrome says ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Unless until there is another rule/code redirecting back to `http` or adding `www` this is no redirect loop. I've already tested this rule on my Apache it works fine.